# Openshift rhc alias-add doesn't work with -l username

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

alias-list works with -l username_2

```
rhc alias-list blog -l username_2
```

wheras

```
rhc alias-add blog www.somedomain.com -l username_2
```

doesn't take into account -l username2 it will create alias for username_1 instead

How to add alias to account 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. thats strange. There is express.conf file in User home ~/.openshift directory. This file has a property called default_rhlogin. Try changing this property with username_2 and check if this works.

Comment: I changed to username_2 in for default_rhlogin (I'm on Windows 8 Pro). When I use alias-list it says no alias which is true, when I tried to add an alias it says already added : so it refers to username_1 because it's true I added this alias to username_1 seems like a bug for me or maybe alias is global. Will delete from username_1 first...

Comment: can you run rhc setup command with username_2. Like rhc setup -l username_2

Comment: OK will test that. Otherwise by removing alias from username_1 and changing  default_rhlogin to username_2 I could finally add alias to username_2

Comment: When rhc setup -l username_2 it changed default_rhlogin to username_2

Comment: So it's ok for me now. Thanks for your help with default_rhlogin.

Answer (score 1):

So I just ran into a similar problem and heres what it was for me. For some reason `rhc` only understood what i was trying to do once I switched to the folder with the app/account I wanted to deal with. Even though I had logged out of the previous account and ran rhc setup for the second account (and included the `-l` option), it was still looking for the domain of the first account.

So to make it work I had to `cd` to the folder containing the app I was trying to alias (as well as actually switching to the right account with logout, and setup or -l). After that it worked perfectly for me. Hope this helps.